# Uninstall Second Passenger on FreeBSD-11.1

Tags: passenger, freebsd

I have two `Passenger` installations from the sheer confusion with installations.  So I'm given an error from some `Passenger` scripts:

```
You are currently validating against Phusion Passenger 5.3.4, located in:

 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5/gems/passenger-5.3.4/bin/passenger

Besides this Passenger installation, the following other
Passenger installations have also been detected:

 /usr/local/bin/passenger

Please uninstall these other Passenger installations to avoid
confusion or conflicts.
```

I'm not sure how I installed the `/usr/local/bin/passenger` version, but I need to uninstall that one.  `pkg info` reveals only `rubygem-passenger-nginx-5.3.4` having `Passenger` mentioned.

Should I rename the latter instead of deleting?  I want to be safe.  As the warning states, it might create (more) confusion and some conflicts.  Best way to turn this `Passenger` off?  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the `FreeBSD` world.  Reference for `FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE`

The **solution** is to not use a `ruby` package manager.  No `RVM`, no `rbenv`.  They're good for your workstation Mac/PC.  **Everything** should be done through ports (`/www/ports`).  Everything.  `Ruby`, then normal gems including `bundler` first, and a proper `Gemfile`.

**Ruby 2.5.1**: `cd /lang/ruby25 && sudo make install clean`

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

**Nginx**: `cd /www/nginx && sudo make install clean`

**Passenger**: `cd /www/rubygem-passenger && sudo make FLAVOR=nginx install clean`

This latter `FLAVOR` is yet *another* layer of complexity to package managers.  The default `FLAVOR` is `Apache`.  This *feature* is less than a year old.  Get to know it as I see multiple `ports` repackaged into a single `port` this way in the future.

Unfortunately this means dropping a lot of policies set forth before `FreeBSD-11.1` with regards to the usual `nginx-passenger-ruby` stacks out there, but it's doable.